# how to use datatables plugin in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, adminlte

how to use datatables plugin in adminlte? I've tried the match on the default page datatables adminlte, but it does not work.
this is my code

```
             <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Rendering engine</th>
                    <th>Browser</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Trident</td>
                    <td>InternetExplorer 4.0</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table>
```

and the scrypt

```
<!-- DataTables -->
 <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css') }}">
```

please help me i dont know why datatables doesnt work, in the console there is no error. btw i use laravel 5.3 and AdminLTE-2.3.0

pagescrypt

```
   <script>
  $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable();
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to remove tbody tag
and this should be like that :

```
        $('#example2').DataTable({
  "paging": true,
  "lengthChange": false,
  "searching": false,
  "ordering": true,
  "info": true,
  "autoWidth": false,
columns:[{'data':'data','name':'name'}]});
```

I suggest to take a look at this tutorail:
https://appdividend.com/2018/04/16/laravel-datatables-tutorial-with-example/